# Disable Analytics/Tracking For each SXA site

Tags: sxa, xdb

I am using Sitecore 10.1 and I have a situation where I need to disable analytics and personalization or can say xConnect for a particular SXA site. Is that possible to keep the setting for each site level not for all sites?

Answer (score 6):

You can disable tracking per site by using `enableTracking="false"`
To do this in SXA, go to Site Grouping, then use the `Other Properties` named value field to add that in.

Official Documentation links:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/platform-administration-and-architecture/enable-disable-the-xdb-and-the-tracker.html

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/101/sitecore-experience-accelerator/the-sxa-site-definition-fields.html

Comment: In my experience, changes to this configuration usually requires an App Pool reset to take effect. Worth noting.

Comment: Yes, It works. I verified by checking the  visitoridentification.js on the page. When I set this to false it doesn't add this JS file on the page.